# Determine how long a sum of $\frac{1}{n}$ is needed to reach a limit

Tags: summation

Since

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n {1 \over i} = \infty
$$

it should be possible to find the $n$ where the sum reaches a certain number.

Given $c$ determine $k$ where

$$
\sum_{i=1}^k {1 \over i} < c \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} {1 \over i}
$$

Approximate solution is also OK if you can determine whether $k$ is even or odd.

Comment: [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) helps you with at least an approximate solution: $k\approx e^{c-\gamma}$

Comment: It is unclear to me how precise that is. Can I just round that value down or will that fail at some point?

Comment: Any approximation will fail for suitably-chosen $c$.

Answer (score 3):

If $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$, we have $L(n) < S_n < U(n)$ where
$$ \eqalign{L(n) &= \ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{12 n^2}\cr
            U(n) &= \ln(n) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}\cr} $$

Now $U(x) = c$ for $$x = -\dfrac{1}{2 W(-\exp(\gamma-c)/2)}$$ 
where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  If $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$, you
have $U(n) \le c \le U(n+1)$.  The difference between $L(n+1)$ and $U(n+1)$ is only $1/(12 (n+1)^2)$, while the difference between $U(n)$ and $U(n+1)$ is approximately
$1/(n+1)$ which is much larger if $n$ is large.  So for "most" $c$, you'll
also have $c \le L(n+1)$, and therefore $S_{n} < c < S_{n+1}$.  But if you're unlucky enough that $c > L(n+1)$, all you have is $L(n+1) < c < U(n+1)$.
You might then try a better approximation.

For example, with $c = 10$, I get 
$x \approx 12366.46810$ so $n = 12366$, and $L(12367) \approx 10.00004301 > c$,
so $S_{12366} < 10 < S_{12367}$.